# How to run MapReduceIndexerTool job from Java?

Tags: java, hadoop, indexing, mapreduce

I want to run MapReduceIndexerTool from Java.

Right now I do it from command line using `hadoop jar` as you can see [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/search_mapreduceindexertool.html), but I want to check it's status (to see if it's finalized, in progress, etc.) from Java code.

So basically I want to run it **from Java** in order to be able to check it's status from Java. Is there a way to run it **from command line** and check it's status from Java?

Also, there is a way to make Map Reduce to send an event (on a callback for example) when a job is completed? Something like a webhook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know Tool interface exposes only `int run(String[] args)` method, so in general you would create new instance, form proper argument string and call that method.

From other hand, [MapReduceIndexerTool](https://github.com/cloudera/search/blob/cdh5-1.0.0_5.2.1/search-mr/src/main/java/org/apache/solr/hadoop/MapReduceIndexerTool.java#L637) has `int run(Options options)` method, that could be used to run it without forming shell-style argument. However, this method is protected, so this will need to have calling class to be created in same package as `MapReduceIndexerTool`.